# Subdomain Issue in Django

Tags: python, django, subdomain, middleware

I'm trying to setup a middleware that will read the subdomain in requests and serve up a different app's urls.py depending on the subdomain...but I'm getting some erratic behavior

Here's my middleware:

```
class SubdomainsMiddleware:
def process_request(self, request):
    request.domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    request.subdomain = ''
    parts = request.domain.split('.')

    if len(parts) == 3 or (re.match("^localhost", parts[-1]) and len(parts) == 2):
        request.subdomain = parts[0]
        request.domain = '.'.join(parts[1:])

    # set the right urlconf
    if request.subdomain == 'foo':
        settings.ROOT_URLCONF = 'bqsite.urls'
    else:
        settings.ROOT_URLCONF = 'dhsite.urls'
```

My understanding is that if this is working, then the root urls.py for the project should never be hit.  Is that correct?  I'm getting really weird and erratic behavior where, if i restart apache, the site shows the django welcome screen but after refrshing uses the right urls file.

Comment: Have a look: http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2008/12/12/handling-subdomains-in-django/

Comment: I think it is not possible to change settings on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You [shouldn't alter your settings at runtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime).

A better approach would be to set the request `urlconf` setting, as hinted in the section [*how django processes a request*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) in the url docs.

```
if request.subdomain == 'foo':
    request.urlconf = 'bqsite.urls'
else:
    request.urlconf = 'dhsite.urls'
```